# flutter blur effect is not working on iOS (ImageFilter.blur)

Tags: android, ios, image, flutter, blur

I am using flutter 2.0.4 and dart 2.12.2

I use following code to add blur effect.

It is working fine on Android but does not provide blur effect on **iOS** devices.

Is there any work around for this ?

Or is there some minimum version of iOS this is working?

```
 Container(
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
              child: ClipRect(
                child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                    sigmaX: 5.0,
                    sigmaY: 5.0,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                    height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade200.withOpacity(0.5)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

on Android blur effect is active
[image]

on iOS grey shading is active but blur effect is not active

[image]

Can anyone provide some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been a long running issue with seemingly no fix yet and seems specific to certain use cases.

More on it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43902)

If you haven't already tried this, what I would rather suggest is to try creating a `Stack` and have your your `Container` on top of whatever view your are trying to blur.

Comment: Adding the Container over the stack is what I was trying to do. But does not seems to work.

Comment: Then unfortunately no solution as of now.